# How do I select Customers who don't have account in Bank Database? The values are present in one table, but are not in the other table

Tags: sql

Select all customers either they have accounts or not.
I have two tables: Customers and Accounts. I have 3 records in customers but they don't appear in accounts table. How do write the query to retrieve these 3?

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking SQL questions. Note that homework related questions are expected to prove some extra effort.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there is a foreign key from one table to the other (for example `customer_id`) you should use [`left join`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp).

```
select customer_id
from customers c
left join accounts a on c.customer_id = a.customer_id
where a.customer_id = null
```

Comment: I don't have a foreign key... The answer is showing me null values on both columns

Comment: it's hard to say without database model, please read about `left join` as it's the answer to your question